# Rational curves covering co-tangent bundle of a Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be smooth Fano variety of dimension $n$ of Picard number one. If $l$ is a rational curve and $T^*X\vert_l$ has a section, then $l$ gives a rational curve in $T^*X$.  Assume $TX$ is not nef, here $TX$ and $T^*X$ denote the tangent and cotangent bundle of $X$ respectively.

Question: Can such rational curves in $T^*X$ cover $T^*X$ as $l$ varies in a component of Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$, possibly of large degree?